# CSS and JQuery not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So the CSS on my site doesn't seem to be working, at least the updates I made. I want to create a height transition effect with the css transition property and the JQuery.css property but my applied changes aren't working on my site.

```
.blog{
    transition: 1500ms ease-in-out !important;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0% !important;
    background-color: #8394EB;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    color: white !important;
}

$('.blog').css('height','100%');
```

Comment: you used `!important` here `height: 0% !important;`  that's why its not affecting, remove `!important`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `height` using `%` might not work in a lot of cases.
Try to use `px`, `rem`, or `vh` instead in both css and your js code and see if it makes any difference.

```
.blog{
    transition: 1500ms ease-in-out !important;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0px;
    background-color: #8394EB;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    color: white !important;
}

$('.blog').css('height','10vh');
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks, except it doesn't give my desired effect. I want my site to be responsive and the only way would be to use 100%. I did try your suggestion and it did work, but not to my liking.

Comment: @GalacticWorld this test demonstrated that your use of % does not work (css problem) and has nothing related to !important and your use of jQuery.

Comment: @GalacticWorld now you just have to figure out a way to use css to set the .blog element to take 100% height of it's container without using `%`. As I said, `%` values does not always work as expected in CSS.

I cannot comment too much without seeing how your HTML is structured and how your other CSS styles are set.

Answer (score 0):

try using “height” = “100%” in your jquery if that don’t work just do document.querySelector(“.blog”).style.height = “100%”

Comment: No affect to the page.

Comment: @williamli your answer will work but will it still scale properly down to mobile. I am not that familiar with vh since I rarely use it I like pixels

Comment: @ItsClubz `vh` works in mobile as it use the `viewport` as reference. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: @ItsClubz it seems the way OP used his HTML / CSS , `%` values does not work for him. Maybe issues with .blog's container.

Comment: @williamli I know how vh works I am just not that familiar with it and you could be right he could have an issue somewhere else in his code that he hasn’t shown

Answer (score 0):

Problem with this line:

```
height: 0% !important;
```

Try remove attribute "important" and it will work.
If this modifier is necessary, use code like below:

```
$( '.blog' ).each(function () {   
    this.style.setProperty( 'height', '10vh', 'important' );
});
```

Hope I help you :)